# Why don't the team ever bring back other species for study?

Tags: stargate, stargate-sg1

During the first episode of Stargate SG1: Children of the Gods, and the second (third?) episode Enemy Within, one of the primary discussions about what Teal'c cannot join SG1 is that he is an alien soldier of the enemy, carrying the larval form of an even more powerful enemy, and must be studied.

Yet, from this point on, thousands of Jaffa are killed by SG teams at various points over the next several seasons, and they never even do as much as discuss bringing one back for study.

Why, since part of the SGC's mandate is to bring back technologies to study, do none of the SG teams ever bring back a captured or killed Jaffa for study?

Comment: Because they have Teal'c to study? Just because he's on the team doesn't mean he isn't (or already has been) studied. Teal'c is not a danger to the SGC or Earth ... the others might be, whether dead or alive.

Comment: They can't do any in depth study on the Goa'uld as it would kill Teal'c (since he requires his symbiote in order to stay alive...)

Comment: He needs his symbiote, until he got the Tritonin. Both host and symbiote can survive without each other for periods of time without detriment to each other. There was plenty of time for both/either/and/or to be studied.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

The very short answer is that there's a considerable amount of action happening *off screen*. SG1 may be the "point-team" (tasked with making first contact and providing situational assessments) but there are numerous other [SG-teams](http://stargate.wikia.com/wiki/SG_team) mentioned that seem to do follow up work. This includes a host of diplomatic teams creating working relationships with alien races, archaeological survey teams, scientific analysis teams and various others.

We see some of these guys in action; SG7 is busy setting up an observatory in "*SG1: Singularity*", SG9 are seen in "*SG1: Icon*" establishing long-term diplomatic ties with the Latonans, SG16 is seen in "*SG1: Ascension*" preparing to conduct a scientific study of an alien weapon, etc etc.

It seems likely that these teams have had ample access to Jaffa (both dead and living) through their various mop-up missions. That's even ignoring the fact that at least one dead Jaffa was left in the gateroom when Apophis attacked.

[image]